# Excel Task Pane - bindingDataChanged event never ends

Tags: javascript, excel, task, pane

I am working on an Excel task pane app. Basically what it does is to change the background color of a cell with an invalid format (r1243 for postal code) when user is typing. I created a binding and added an event handler of BindingDataChanged which listens for the data change. If there are any changes, validate the format, and change the background color. The codes are as follows.

The codes were kind of working, but the problem was that onBindingDataChanges seems to never end even when there aren't any changes on data. What could be wrong?

```
function listenChanges() {
    Office.select("bindings#customerTableBinding").addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged, onBindingDataChanged, function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
            app.showNotification('Error: ' + asyncResult.error.message);
        } else {
            app.showNotification('New event handler added for binding.');
        }
    });
}

function onBindingDataChanged(eventArgs) {
    eventArgs.binding.getDataAsync({coercionType: 'table'},
     function (asyncResult) {
         if (asyncResult.status == 'succeeded') {
             var table = new Office.TableData();
             table.headers = asyncResult.value.headers;
             table.rows = asyncResult.value.rows;

             var column = getColumns(table);
             var rows = getRows(table, column);

             eventArgs.binding.setFormatsAsync([{ cells: Office.Table.Data, format: { backgroundColor: "white" } }], function (asyncResult) { });

             for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                 eventArgs.binding.setFormatsAsync([{ cells: { row: rows[i], column: column }, format: { backgroundColor: "red", fontStyle: "bold" } }], function (asyncResult) { });
             }
         }
         else
             app.showNotification("The error message is " + asyncResult.error.message);
     });
}

function getColumns(table) {
    var column;
    for (var i = 0; i < table.headers.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < table.headers[i].length; j++) {
            if (table.headers[i][j] == "PostalCode") {
                column = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return column;
}

function getRows(table, column) {
    var rows = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
        if (!isValidUSZip(table.rows[i][column])) {
            rows.push(i);
        }
    }
    return rows;
}

function isValidUSZip(zip) {
    return /^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$/.test(zip);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

eventArgs.binding.setFormatsAsync([{ cells: Office.Table.Data, format: { backgroundColor: "white" } }], function (asyncResult) { });

You are setting the background to white everytime the change event fires.  This will trigger the change event to fire again (causing an infinite loop).  To solve this you could remove the handler when the data event action is triggered and then add it back after you have made your update.

```
function addHandlerChanged() {
    if (selfBinding) {
        selfBinding.addHandlerAsync(
           Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged, dataChangeEvent);
    }
}

function removeHandlerChanged() {
    if (selfBinding) {
        selfBinding.removeHandlerAsync(
           Office.EventType.BindingDataChanged, { handler: dataChangeEvent }, function (result) {
           });
    }
};

function dataChangeEvent(eventArgs) {    
  //remove handler
  removeHandlerChanged();

   // do you're table format update here

   //then add the handler back 

   addHandlerChanged();
}
```